# How to check if value is not smaller (!<=) or bigger (!>=) than value x?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, air

How to check if value is not smaller (!<=) or bigger (!>=) than value x?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Why dont you use number `(>)` to compare if its `(!<=)` and number `(<)` to compare `(!>=)`

Answer (score 1):

Simple:

```
var value:int = 10;

if(value > 5)
{
    trace("will trace");

}// end if

if(!(value > 5))
{
    trace("will not trace");

}// end if
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you are talking about 2 operations (other wise there is no such number).
so you should use

```
if(number >=x){//which means he is larger.

}else if(number<=x){//which means he is smaller.

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If x and y are both numbers then x <= y || x >= y one of them has to be true (or both if x == y). Using logical not in this fashion can make things less readable but you would do it like this.

x !>= y would actually need to be !(x >= y)

x >= y is the same as !(x <= y)
x <= y is the same as !(x >= y)

Operators in AS3 from the live docs can be found at: http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/operators.html

Comment: This is not true: "x >= y is the same as !(x <= y)" , the second should be !(x < y) since if x == y then x>=y is `true` but !(x<=y) is `false`